# JobTracker source code modification

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a student studying the MapReduce research.  Now,  I have designed a MapReduce scheduling message.  I will implement the algorithm.  For validating the algorithm, I add some print messages on the original Hadoop codes, e.g., JobTracker.java, FairScheduler.java, etc...  However, after re-compiling the codes,  the print message is not shown on the display.  I cannot validate the correctness of my algorithm.

For example, the modified codes in the src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.java are as follows.

```
...

public static JobTracker startTracker(JobConf conf
                                        ) throws IOException,
                                                 InterruptedException {       System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");
    return startTracker(conf, generateNewIdentifier());   }

  public static JobTracker startTracker(JobConf conf, String identifier)    throws IOException, InterruptedException {    System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");    return startTracker(conf, identifier, false);   }
     public static JobTracker startTracker(JobConf conf, String identifier, boolean initialize)    throws IOException, InterruptedException {     System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");    DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize("JobTracker");
    JobTracker result = null;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");
      try {
        result = new JobTracker(conf, identifier);
        result.taskScheduler.setTaskTrackerManager(result);
        break;
      } catch (VersionMismatch e) {
        throw e;
      } catch (BindException e) {
        throw e;
      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw e;
      } catch (AccessControlException ace) {
        // in case of jobtracker not having right access
        // bail out
        throw ace;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.warn("Error starting tracker: " + 
                 StringUtils.stringifyException(e));
      }
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    if (result != null) {
        System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");
      JobEndNotifier.startNotifier();
      MBeans.register("JobTracker", "JobTrackerInfo", result);
      if(initialize == true) {
          System.out.println("Hello! World!!!");
        result.setSafeModeInternal(SafeModeAction.SAFEMODE_ENTER);
        result.initializeFilesystem();
        result.setSafeModeInternal(SafeModeAction.SAFEMODE_LEAVE);
        result.initialize();
      }
    }
    return result;   }

...
```

I compiled the modified codes and replaced original Hadoop by the commands:

```
cd $HADOOP_HOME
ant
mv build/hadoop-client-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar hadoop-client-1.2.1.jar
mv build/hadoop-core-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
mv build/hadoop-minicluster-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar hadoop-minicluster-1.2.1.jar
mv build/hadoop-tools-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar hadoop-tools-1.2.1.jar
```

Then, I started up the new version of Hadoop. 
It didn't show any "Hello! World!!!" message on my monitor.

If you know the reason, please advice me.  In compiling or executions, is it required to add some parameters?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of Hadoop daemons are captured in *.out under $HADOOP_HOME/logs folder by default. You should be able to find the output messages there.